# Customize Ubercart checkout page CSS when certain products are in cart?

Tags: ubercart

On my Drupal 6 / Ubercart 2.9 cart website, I have the need to modify the CSS of the checkout page when a certain product is in the cart. For instance, if the customer is ordering red flowers, the background would change to a red flower background image. Is this possible via CSS? If not, any other ideas on how it can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two ideas:

1) render **the code of the article in the class attribute** of the cart div. you can do that "intercepting" the render function in your template.php file.

2) **using jquery**

Comment: Do you have an example of the jquery method that you can point me towards?

Comment: Also, what about passing a value in the URL? Is that a possible method of providing the ability to customize the CSS for that page based on whether that parameter is passed in the URL? If so, how would that be accomplished?

Comment: JQUERY: I opened an ubercart cart and saw that -unfortunally- there wasn't an id of the product mentioned in the html <tr>. But there was the href (yourdomain/catalog/section/productname). So you can solve with this line of code in your script head tag:
`$(document).ready(function () { 
 if ($("a['yourdomain/catalog/section/productname']")) { 
  $("#cart-form-pane").css('background','red') 
 }
});`

Comment: URL: instead of url, you can intercept the cart render  function in yourthemename/template.php file, in order to append a class to the <div id='cart-form-pane'> tag. But I can't help you there...maybe this post could be useful: [www.ubercart.org/forum/development/3868/nifty_products_tutorial_part_1](http://www.ubercart.org/forum/development/3868/nifty_products_tutorial_part_1)

Comment: I might need a little more help on this. The Jquery method is working perfectly on a test site and on one live site, but it is not working on another live site. The FireFox error console shows this error... **Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ['mysite.com/node/255']** . It throws that same error when I use the product's url alias in the js code as well. Any idea why that would happen, and how I might troubleshoot it?

Comment: Looks like the Jquery Update (http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module was causing the issue. I disabled that module, and the jquery method now works fine on that other live site.